# error while predicting test data in xgboost python

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, xgboost, countvectorizer

I am using xgboost python to perform text classification

Below is the trainset I am considering

```
itemid       description                                            category
11802974     SPRO VUH3C1 DIFFUSER VUH1 TRIPLE Space heaters    Architectural Diffusers
10688548     ANTIQUE BRONZE FINISH PUSHBUTTON  switch           Door Bell Pushbuttons
9836436     Descente pour Cable tray fitting and accessories    Tray Cable Drop Outs
```

I am constructing document term matrix of description using Sckit learn's counvectorizer which generate scipy matrix(As I have huge data of 1.1million I am using sparse representation to reduce space complexity) using below code

```
countvec = CountVectorizer()
documenttermmatrix=countvec.fit_transform(trainset['description'])
```

After that I will apply feature selection for the above matrix using

```
 fs = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.chi2, percentile=40)
 documenttermmatrix_train= fs.fit_transform(documenttermmatrix,y1_train)
```

I am using xgboost classifier to train the model

```
model = XGBClassifier(silent=False)

model.fit(documenttermmatrix_train, y_train,verbose=True)
```

Below is the testset i am considering

```
itemid      description                       category
9836442     TRIPLE Space heaters              Architectural Diffusers
13863918    pushbutton switch                  Door Bell Pushbuttons
```

I am constructing seperate matrix for test set as I did it for train set  using below code

```
 documenttermmatrix_test=countvec.fit_transform(testset['description'])
```

while preicting testset Xgboost expects all the features of trainset to be in testset but it is not possible( sparse matrix represents only non-zero entries)

I cannot combine train and test set into single dataset as i need to do feature selection only for trainset

Can anyone tell how can I approach further?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `countvec.fit_transform()` on testset, only use `transform()`.

Change this line:

```
documenttermmatrix_test=countvec.fit_transform(testset['description'])
```

To this:

```
documenttermmatrix_test=countvec.transform(testset['description'])
```

This will make sure that those features which are present in training set are only taken from the test set and if not available, put 0 there.

fit_transform() will forget the previous trained data and make new matrix which can have different features than previous output. Hence the error.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. As I have set vocabulary of countvectorizer to train set features using line    _countvec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=trainset_features)_ in _documenttermmatrix_test_ I have features only from trainset. but in different order. I think different order is the problem. While predicting its expects trainset and test set features to be in same order it seems.....But I am not getting how to make them in same order.

Comment: @RanjanaGirish It doesnt matter. If you use CountVectorizer correctly, it will automatically return them in same order. Please explain the `vocabulary=trainset_features`. How did you make it? Also, please add this detail in the question. There you have not mentioned about it.

Comment: `countvec = CountVectorizer()`
`documenttermmatrix=countvec.fit_transform(trainset['description'])`     `fs = feature_selection.SelectPercentile(feature_selection.chi2, percentile=40)`
`documenttermmatrix_train= fs.fit_transform(documenttermmatrix,y1_train)`
`terms=np.asarray(countvec.get_feature_names())[fs.get_support()]`
`trainset_features=set(terms)` . This is how I am making _trainset_features_.

Comment: @RanjanaGirish So are you again declaring the `countVec`? Initializing it again? If not, then no need to do this. Just use the original countVec with which you trained the data. Its vocabulary is already set with the training data features.

Comment: In vocabulary of countvectorizer initialized for construction of train set matrix I will be having all the terms in description of trainset. Later I will apply feature selection for that and get important terms. I will train only using those important terms (trainset_features). So i will again initialize count vectorizer with `vocabulary=trainset_features` to construct test set matrix. If i consider only one there will be vary in index for same  feature in train and test set know(countvectorizer results in scipy matrix which has index for features without names. Is it wrong what I am doing?

Comment: @RanjanaGirish Well, when you again initialize and  train the countVectorizer with your vocabulary, then only use that countvec object to transform the test set.

Comment: I am transforming test set with second countVectorizer itself.

Comment: @RanjanaGirish Then no need to do any other processing on that. The returned array will be in the same order.

Comment: yes true. But why I am getting **expected f35215 in input data** while predicting test set?

Comment: @RanjanaGirish Please add the full stack trace of error and complete code in the question. That issue is not easy to analyse without some data.

Comment: I will add a simple scenario describing the flow as you have said in some time in this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `fit_transform` on train set, but only transform on your test set. Therefore the default output of `countvectorizer` is a csr matrix. It doesn't work with `XGBClissifier`, you have to convert it to csc matrix. Simply do: `X = csc_matrix(X)`.

Comment: @RanjanaGirish Please follow this answer in addition to mine. This seems to be the issue you are getting when predicting (`expected f35215 in input data`). Also make sure to use csc_matrix() during fitting also.

Comment: @RanjanaGirish This seems to be an issue of XGBoost not handling sparse matrices correctly. https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1238

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way around this issue, common as it is. XGBoost and other tree-based models can handle test sets with **more** variables than the training set (since it can ignore them), but never fewer (since it's expecting to make decisions on them). That being the case, you have some options, in descending order of desirability / likelihood to solve your problem:

1. **Don't use a sparse matrix.** Unless you're building this model inside a real-time application or otherwise prohibitive production environment, the easiest thing to do is use an ordinary matrix that will keep columns of zeros.
2. **Look at how you're partitioning your data.** It may be that there are only one or two factors with an unbalanced split, in which case you might be able to get more equal representation by playing around with scikit learn's `train_test_split()` [functionality](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html).
3. **Prune the data yourself**. Similar to option 2, if you think a couple entries are the culprits, and that their removal wouldn't hurt your model, you can try removing them from the original dataset. This is, of course, the least desirable option, but if they really are that few and far between, they won't affect the predictive power of your model.

But broadly this is a sign of an unhealthy dataset. I would also advise looking at other ways you might bin or categorize your data into fewer groups so that this isn't a problem.

Comment: ..Thank you so much for your thoughts. I tried one approach. i kept the list of train set feature in list and constructed matrix of test set using train set feature as vocabulary. i.e_ countvec = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=trainset_features)_, _documenttermmatrix_test=countvec.fit_transform(testset['ProductDescription'])_. i have list of 35216 features. still i got _ error expected f35215 in input data_.....when i see value of that column using   _print(documenttermmatrix_test.getcol(35215))_ there was no value .whether error is because of this, can anyone please tel me

Comment: If above is the case for _print(documenttermmatrix_test.getcol(35213))_ there was no value. why it didnt give error _expected f35213, f35215 in input data_